# How do I copy and paste files from one directory to another using the mouse?

Tags: mouse, directory, paste

On Microsoft Windows, I right-click on the file and choose "Copy". I place my cursor on the target directory, right-click on it and choose "Paste". The file will be copied to the target folder.

It seems that Ubuntu 12.10 does not have this function.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: How are you trying to do the copy?. This is quite standard stuff and should work as you described.

Comment: @JavierRivera permissions ... permissions ... you can not paste if user does not own the disc in some fashion.

Comment: @ Rinzwind: It's my own home computer.

Comment: @Rinzwind: But there still is a paste option in Nautilus, it's just disabled (greyed out). And the copy option is enabled. There must be something more there with OP.

Comment: Greyed out has 2 reasons: - there is nothing to copy (ie. nothing selected). - user is not allowed to copy to that destination.

Answer (score 4):

> It seems that Ubuntu 12.10 does not have this function.

Yes, it does. In exactly the same way. Example image:

[image]

It shows both cut (move) and copy as options. Paste is added/highlighted when you have something to paste:

[image]

The only reservations I have with this:

- You need to have permissions to use the location you want to move/copy files to. If you do not you need to have the admin of that system open that location for that user.

> Is there a workaround?

No and not needed either.

Comment: @ Rinzwind: It's my own home computer.

Comment: Cool :-) but still: you are a user of that system. but the destination can still be owned by your admin and not you as a user. Can you edit your question and add in images like I did? And maybe check if you own the destination (/are allowed to use it). The answer to this you can add to the questions (comments get removed so those are not good for that ;) )

Comment: @ Rinzwind: I don't have "Nau-T" option when I right-click on the file to be moved/copied. What happened?

Comment: @noob that is a custom script probably. It is not important for your questions (that image is just to show that there is a copy command)

Comment: @ Rinzwind: How do I add images? and how do I check if I own the destination? Any sudo commands that I need to issue?

Comment: Just upload your images somewhere on the internet and put a link in your question, we will sort it out afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

My 12.10 installation using session fall back desktop environment provides these option once a file is selected and right-click on that file
[image: Nautilis] Applications | Accessories | ScreenShot is available to aid taking screen shots